# Reactivity in jQuery-generated contenteditable elements (Meteor 0.8.0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I've been having problems with `contenteditable` elements generated via jQuery since Meteor 0.8.0 (Blaze template engine).

This is my setup (I'm using [Medium Editor](https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor)):

**post_page.html:**

```
<template name="postPage">
  <div class="sidebar col-md-4">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
    <a class="save-all" href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span></a>
  </div>

  <div class="mainbar col-md-12">
  <form class="form" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div name="content" class="form-control" id="input-content">{{{content}}}</div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

**post_page.js:**

```
Template.postPage.rendered = function() {
  var editor;
  editor = new MediumEditor("#input-content", {
    placeholder: ""
  });
};
```

**post_item.html:**

```
<template name="postItem">
  <div class="post clearfix {{title}}">
    <div class="post-buttons">
      <a class="move-up" href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>
      <a class="move-down" href="javascript:;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span></a>
    </div>
    <h2><a class="open-post" href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}">{{title}}</a></h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

**routes.js:**

```
this.route("postPage", {
  path: "/posts/:_id",
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne(this.params._id);
  }
});
```

Even though I click in an item in the posts list, the `{{{content}}}` inside the `contenteditable` div doesn't change (remains the same all the time). For some reason, reactivity is not working in this case.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using the latest upstream medium-editor?  I was using one of the atmosphere packages and having all kinds of trouble.  Switching to the latest `medium-editor.js` (v1.8.8) solved my problems.